# Failed to resolve assembly "Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS" error after adding Xamarin Forms Labs

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added Xamarin Forms Labs 1.2.O from NuGet to the iOS project. The same project also references Xamarin Forms dll, v1.3.0.6292.

After adding the Xamarin labs reference and updating `AppDelegate` to inherit from `XFormsApplicationDelegate`, I keep getting this compile time error:

> MTOUCHTASK: error MT2002: Failed to resolve assembly: 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=1.2.3.0 ...

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Xamarin.Forms 1.3 you needed to update to the latest pre-release of Xamarin.Labs which is Xamarin.Forms.Labs 1.2.1-pre2.

Try updating to that to see if it works.